# Do SQLDatabases get closed if an App crashes due to other unhanded Exceptions?

Tags: java, sqlite, exception

After reading upon Database SQL best practices, i have extracted two try catches  into two separate methods. The only thing that I can think of which create a Database leak is if there is an external unhanded exception after doing `getReadableDatabase()`. So my question is, if an app crashes and restarts does the app clean itself up? For example help me closing this database session?  As you can see i don't fully quite understand what happens after an App crashes/ restarts.

```
  try {
            SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
            doALongDatabaseTask(database);
            database.close();
        } catch (SQLException e){
            Log.w(Util.TAG, "getButtonPairsForSending db cannot be opened " + e);
        }

public void doALongDatabaseTask(SQLiteDatabase database){
 try
 {
   // Do long database query task
   } catch(Exception e) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example method `doALongDatabaseTask(SQLiteDatabase database)` the exception is handled, its just nothing is done with it, so in this case your database would call `close()`

However, if your method was defined to throw an exceptions

```
public void doALongDatabaseTask(SQLiteDatabase database) throws Exception{...}
```

then your call to close would be skipped, as it goes into the catch block in the first part of the example given.

Provided your using a high enough sdk version: If you look at the docs for [`SQLiteDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#protected-methods) you can see that it implements the interface `AutoCloseable`.
This means that you can use a try with resources which looks like this

```
try(SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase()){
    doALongDatabaseTask(database);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printstacktrace();
}
```

This is the equivalent of calling `database.close()` in a finally block (which you should be doing anyway) but much more readable. This then should in most cases clean up the connections when your app crashes and on a restart fresh connections can be obtained.